# QImage Custom Indexed Colors Using setColorTable

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, color-space

In my project I need to convert an image with many colors to one that only uses any of the 144 predetermined colors I set in a custom colorTable.

Here is my code:

```
    QImage convImage(128, 128, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    convImage.setColorCount(144);
    convImage.setColorTable(colorTable); //colorTable is a const QVector with 144 qRgb values.

    //scaledImage is the source image
    convImage = scaledImage.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Indexed8,Qt::ThresholdDither|Qt::AutoColor);

    ui->mapView->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(convImage));
```

I would expect convImage to only contain colors that exist in the colorTable I created, however it seems to completely ignore the table I set and instead creates it's own unique table with 256 max colors.

I could index everything myself by looping through every pixel and find a way to accurately select a color from the colorTable, but I am wondering if I am just using the colorTable wrong. I couldn't find anything in the documentation that explains why a new table is being created.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ask yourself: how should the `convertToFormat()` call on `scaledImage` possibly know about the colortable you applied to `convImage`? It doesn't know anything about the `convImage` on the left-hand-side.

Fortunately, there's an overload of `convertToFormat` that takes a colortable and should do the job:

```
QImage convImage = scaledImage.convertToFormat (QImage::Format_Indexed8, 
                                                colorTable,                                
                                                Qt::ThresholdDither|Qt::AutoColor);
```

Comment: Ah perfect! How did I miss that? Saved me a bunch of time. I'm curious though, do you know which technique is used to determine which color is closest?

Comment: Hmmm, turns out that diffuse dithering is no longer working if I specify a color table...

Comment: Right; the docs say: *"Conversion from 32 bit to 8 bit indexed is a slow operation and will use a straightforward nearest color approach, with no dithering."* I have never used colortable images myself...